# Using React Router and Webpack 2 how to require external libraries only on certain routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, react-router

## Currently working

Using Webpack 2 and React Router v4 I have been able to set up working code splitting. There is an intermediate `<AsyncComponent>` that resolves the promise and returns the component (a pattern found on github issues).

An example set of routes below:

```
<Switch>
    <Route 
        path="me" 
        render={(props) => 
            <AsyncComponent promise={ require.ensure([], (require) => require('./modules/Profile'), 'profile') } props={props} />
        } 
    />
    <Route 
        path="credit-card" 
        render={(props) => 
            <AsyncComponent promise={ require.ensure([], (require) => require('./modules/CreditCard'), 'credit-card') } props={props} />
        } 
    />
</Switch>
```

## Objective

I would like to extend that further, and for **certain routes only**, load in additional libraries. In the example above, I would like to fetch the StripeJS (https://js.stripe.com/v2/) library *only* when on the credit card route.

I want to emphasise that I can load Stripe directly into the footer and all works normally. There are multiple libraries, I'm using Stripe as an easy to digest example.

## Attempted

The following has been attempted to little success:

- Marking the lib external within the webpack config. This (correctly) flags the library as being external and won't attempt to bundle it during the resolve sequence of a require. However the expectation is that the library is manually brought in.
- I have played with the idea of using a pseudo script loader (when hitting that route, manually create a `<script>` with a `src` attribute, wait for it to load, then let the component do its thing. This works ok, but is really horrible from a maintainability (if two or more libraries are needed, I then need to replicate the clumsy manual `script` load) point of view and seems to work against the webpack "way".

## Relevant parts of the config

```
const core = [
    'lodash',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'axios',
    'react-router-dom',
];

const config = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './ts_build'),
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    },
    entry: {
        app: './app.js',
        core: core,
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[id].chunk.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './../../public'),
        publicPath: 'http://example.org/',
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./src'),
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['core'], 
            minChunks: Infinity,
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben Everard for the edit - damn my spelling (ie my oven mitts that I call hands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/hinok/webpack2-react-router-code-splitting

Repository contains `webpack2` + `react-router v4` + implemented `code splitting` using dynamic [import()](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-dynamic-import/) and loading external libraries on demand only once by using [loadjs](https://github.com/muicss/loadjs). As example it loads `Stripe.js` for specific route.

In repository you can find two ways to do code splitting

- [by route config](https://github.com/hinok/webpack2-react-router-code-splitting/blob/master/src/routes.js)
- [by component](https://github.com/hinok/webpack2-react-router-code-splitting/blob/master/src/views/StripeLazily.js)

It's based on official Webpack documentation and gist by Andrew Clark

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-load-react/
- https://gist.github.com/acdlite/a68433004f9d6b4cbc83b5cc3990c194

While preparing that repository I found that @Chris would like to load `Stripe.js` only for certain routes which is hosted on external CDN. Since then I've been thinking about the best way to use also AMD modules and avoid leaking global variables but this is a bit tricky because each AMD module could have different wrapper, by saying wrapper I mean something like:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['b'], function (b) {
            return (root.amdWebGlobal = factory(b));
        });
    } else {
        root.amdWebGlobal = factory(root.b);
    }
}(this, function (b) {
    return {};
}));
```

I could say that [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) wrapper is kind of standard but sometimes people prefer less opinionated wrappers or they just don't care about other environments. I'm mentioning it because in the git history, you can find [commit called Amdify](https://github.com/hinok/webpack2-react-router-code-splitting/blob/86e20774893b4fb576b81de2b7980af052609004/src/lib/importScripts.js) which was more proof of concept how AMD env could be simulated. Finally I decided to remove it because it's far from ideal and it doesn't cover all usages and edge cases.

I couldn't find any information about integrating external AMD modules or using AMD modules in some way with webpack. On the contrary I found that it will just not work

> @mc-zone you should be able to load AMD modules with script.js. But this has nothing to do with webpack, it just works because AMD was designed for this. Thus you won't be able to use webpack features inside these AMD modules. webpack requires static analysis on build time.

by @jhns [see on github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150#issuecomment-187617199)

> webpack doesn't handle script loading. Use an separate library for this. i. e. https://github.com/ded/script.js/

by @sokra [see on github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader/issues/7#issuecomment-94654266)

> If it's not possible you should not require() it but load it via a script-loader like script.js.

by @jhns [see on github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/274#issuecomment-43481755)

Related issues on Github:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/462
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/240
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/274
- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader/issues/7

---

Today I found [an article by James Kale](https://medium.com/@thejameskyle/react-loadable-2674c59de178#.lrm85k7hg) on medium about his project [react-loadable](https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable) which do almost the same thing as `LazilyLoad` component but with promise that

- it supports server-side rendering via a dynamic require()
- it eagerly preloads components when needed

I highly recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack 2 you use `import()` in your React Router config file

```
export default {
 component: App,
 childRoutes: [
   {
     path: '/',
     getComponent(location, cb) {
       import('external-library-here')
       .then(function(){
         return System.import('pages/Home');
       })
      .then(loadRoute(cb)).catch(errorLoading);
     }
   },
   {
     path: 'blog',
     getComponent(location, cb) {
       import('pages/Blog').then(loadRoute(cb)).catch(errorLoading);
     }
   },
   {
     path: 'about',
     getComponent(location, cb) {
       import('pages/About').then(loadRoute(cb)).catch(errorLoading);
     }
   },
 ]
};
```

You can also use the `getComponent` or `getComponents` props in the `Router` component to pass in modules you want specifically for that route.

Comment: I think you are spot on in regards to using `System.import` - I'm migrating from a WebpackV1 project, so require.ensure probably should be swapped out. In saying that - my understanding is that `System.import` == `require.ensure`, and the answer above mirrors the ensure pattern I am using above. My question is more about expanding that out further - how do I require (or import) on certain routes particular external libraries. For example, using your answer, maybe that is `System.import('stripe.js').then(System.import('blog').then(loadRoute(cb))`

Comment: Sorry for the late response - didn't get pinged on the comment. I believe - yes - you have to do chaining because System.import returns a promise (like you just said). I updated the answer for clarity for the next person reading this.

Comment: Quick question - where is `loadRoute` coming from? I understand `cb`, but haven't seen loadRoute documented?

Comment: In fact this doesn't work in regards to the original question - it's using RR2 syntax and System.import doesn't accept external urls. Also Webpack 2 has deprecated System.import Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases in this question that should be taken in detail.

Let's start.

### Observations

- You should switch the use of `react-router` from components to [`PlainRoute`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#plainroute) object,  this will give you more flexibility when it comes to doing the code splitting, and also skips the creation of `<AsyncComponent>` component
- I'm pretty sure you are going to have more nested components within your route, so what if a nested component within `credit-card` route needs a library?

### Suggestions

- Use your route component as an entry point, so it doesn't become a huge implementation in a single component
- Given the above suggestion, you can add there an index with your library dependencies and use them within that route (in you nested components)
- You should not import these libraries in any part of the code otherwise this functionality breaks
- Once you have loaded these libraries inject them in the window object. and your nested components will able to access globally to your libraries

> **This is a suggestion that has not been implemented, but I'm trying to take you in the right direction regarding your question**

In the end, this is the approach that I have suggested:

```
import App from 'components/App';

function errorLoading(err) {
  console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err);
}

function loadRoute(cb) {
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}

function injectLibraries(libraries) {
  Object.keys(libraries).forEach(key => {
    window[key] = libraries[key];
  });
}

export default {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/(index.html)',
      name: 'home',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          import('components/HomePage/'),
          import('components/HomePage/libraries'),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadRoute(cb);

        importModules.then(([component, libraries]) => {
          injectLibraries(libraries);
          renderRoute(component);
        });

        importModules.catch(errorLoading);
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/credit-card',
      name: 'credit-card',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          import('components/CreditCardPage/'),
          import('components/CreditCardPage/libraries'),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadRoute(cb);

        importModules.then(([component, libraries]) => {
          injectLibraries(libraries);
          renderRoute(component);
        });

        importModules.catch(errorLoading);
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Your libraries file should look like this:

```
import stripe from 'stripe';

export default {
  stripe 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. RR4 no longer supports plain route. System.import is also deprecated in webpack2. Otherwise the answer is somewhat on the right track - but libraries like Stripe can't be imported the way you mention in the final library file because they are remotely located (basically like a cdn)

Comment: @Chris I prepared a repository to answer your question and I will publish long answer today evening when I back from work to home. Stay tuned - RR4 + Webpack2 + Code Splitting without System.import() or require.ensure ;)

Comment: @hinok looking forward to it! Make sure to include it as a seperate answer so you can get correct credit.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into:

https://github.com/faceyspacey/webpack-flush-chunks

https://github.com/faceyspacey/require-universal-module

The latter is a general purpose package geared toward creating modules that have the need of BOTH synchronously and asynchronously requiring other modules.

This package is what you use to flush the Webpack chunks that were determined to be needed by the request:

https://github.com/faceyspacey/webpack-flush-chunks

It's not React Router specific, which likely means it's more straightforward and requires less workarounds.